# PHP: saveHTML() function is not returning <frameset> objects

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am trying to grab the HTML code from a page as follows:

```
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

This works well except it seems to omit the `<frameset>` tags.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: how about using `file_get_content()`?

Comment: that doesnt work either